# List out distinct attributes in one column for distinct IDs

Tags: mysql, distinct

right now I am getting duplicates on an ID because it has unique attributes. Example and query below

Current:

```
Select distinct ID, Company
from Order
```

| ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 1100 | Fisher |
| 1100 | Nesses |
| 1101 | Denny's |
| 1101 | Labor Inc |

I would like to have a table where the unique Company values are listed in one column and which will remove duplicates on ID

desired:

| ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 1100 | Fisher, Nesses |
| 1101 | Denny's, Labor Inc |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(company SEPARATOR ", ") AS companies
    FROM `order`
    GROUP BY id
```